# Golang gin-gonic JSON binding

Tags: json, pointers, go

I have the struct below

```
type foos struct { Foo string `json:"foo" binding:"required"`}
```

and I have the following endpoint

```
  func sendFoo(c *gin.Context) {
      var json *foos

      if err := c.BindJSON(&json); err != nil {
          c.AbortWithStatus(400)
          return
      }

      // Do something about json
   }
```

when I post this JSON

```
{"bar":"bar bar"}
```

the err is always nil. I write binding required and it doesn't work. But when I change the endpoint like below,

```
func sendFoo(c *gin.Context) {
    var json foos //remove pointer

    if err := c.BindJSON(&json); err != nil {
          c.AbortWithStatus(400)
          return
    }

    // Do something about json
}
```

binding works and the err is not nil. Why?

Comment: What happens if you do `c.BindJSON(json)` in the first case?

Comment: you can't do it, it will cause unmarshall error

Comment: Could you please elaborate? How passing a pointer would "cause unmarshall error", if it does not do so in the second case? What if you initialise the pointer `var json *foos = &foos{}` or `json := &foos{}` and simply pass `json`?

Comment: the all endpoint I mentioned is not causing any error. When you initialize `var json *foos` and you just use `c.BindJSON(json)` it's return unmarshal error because json is the value of *foos which is nil, and &json will pass the pointer address which will initialized in json.decode.

Comment: When you do `&json` for a variable of `*foos` type you get a pointer to a pointer. It correctly tells you about it being `null` since you did not initialise it, like `json := &foos{}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is documented in [binding.go](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin/blob/master/binding/binding.go), lines 25-32 :

```
type StructValidator interface {
    // ValidateStruct can receive any kind of type and it should never panic, even if the configuration is not right.
    // If the received type is not a struct, any validation should be skipped and nil must be returned.
    // If the received type is a struct or pointer to a struct, the validation should be performed.
    // If the struct is not valid or the validation itself fails, a descriptive error should be returned.
    // Otherwise nil must be returned.
    ValidateStruct(interface{}) error
}
```

In your case, ValidateStruct receives a pointer to a pointer to a struct, and no checking takes place, as documented.